# How to correctly create task using asyncio and use a list of tasks?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine

I am not using asyncio correctly.
I think the reason is - I don't know where to put the asyncio.create_task(api_single_call).
I tried but I have tried but the code does not run, mentioning issues on coroutine.
This code runs but it runs the same time as sequentially...

Any idea please do not hesitate to share
Thanks

---

```
data_list = []

async def api_single_call(client,symbol):
    data = client.get_data(symbol=symbol)
    data_list.append(data)
    return None

def get_task_list(client):
    tickers = get_info_tickers(client)
    task_list = [api_single_call(client,symbol) for symbol in tickers]
    return task_list  

async def main(client):
    task_list = get_task_list(client)
    api_calls = await asyncio.gather(*task_list)
    print(data_list)
    return None

asyncio.run(main(client))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `client.get_data` in `api_single_call`  async ?

If it is, you should `await` it.

Comment: yes it is. Should i do something like data = await client.get_data(symbol=symbol) ?
This returns object dict can't be used in 'await' expression

Comment: @H_Zimmer That's might be the method was not  async at all. Can you provide a more detailed error output?

Comment: line 15, in <module>   asyncio.run(file.main(client))
\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 43, in runreturn loop.run_until_complete(main)
  \lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 587, in run_until_complete return future.result()
\fonctions.py", line 82, in main api_calls = await asyncio.gather(*task_list)
 line 72, in task    data = await client.api_call(symbol=symbol)
TypeError: object dict can't be used in 'await' expression

Comment: @H_Zimmer Did you implement `api_call` method in async manner?